# Trying to get google maps geocoding to work with Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, geocoding, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Functions for Firebase to execute geocoding code on the server side. In the code below, `sortDistance` is just an endpoint I am using to execute the geocoding. The variable `snapadd` is showing up as empty when it should have an address in it - I have verified that `console.log(snapadd + " snap user address (((((((())))))))");` outputs an address each time it loops through `snap`. It loops through all the addresses, and then it tries to do the queries, so I'm wondering if its a problem with how I am using the `Promise`...maybe the address isn't there when it needs to be because it looped through all of them before executing a geocode request - so when the geocode request happens, the address is empty? I'm not sure.

```
var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: 'xxx',
  Promise: Promise
});

...

exports.sortDistance = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
    const original = req.query.text;
    console.log(req.query.text + "     request body .......");
  // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("profiles/stylists");
    var promises = [];
    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      //console.log(snapshot.val());
      var snap = snapshot.val();
      for(const user in snap) {
        //promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var snapadd = snap[user].address;
            console.log(snapadd + " snap user address (((((((())))))))");
            if(snapadd != null || typeof snapadd != undefined) {
                    googleMapsClient.geocode({
                      address: snapadd
                    }).asPromise()
                        .then(response =>  console.log(response.json.results));
                        .catch(err => console.log(err))
            }   
        //}))
        //console.log(typeof user + 'type of');

      }

      //var p = Promise.all(promises);
      //console.log(p +     "     promises logged");

    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
});
```

I am getting this as an error back from `firebase functions` log:

```
{ error_message: 'Invalid request. Missing the \'address\', \'bounds\', \'components\', \'latlng\' or \'place_id\' parameter.',
     results: [],
     status: 'INVALID_REQUEST' },
  requestUrl: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=&key=AIzaSyBzXEp6HR01Pau5cotJ2wve1Z7aKEfvkUI',
  query: { address: '', key: 'xxx' } }
```

Obviously the address is being shown as empty when it shouldn't be. Again, viewing the order of the logs, it looks like all the addresses are looped through before a single geocode request happens. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear why your `snapadd` is missing (I can't see into your database to make sure your query is correct), but I can tell you that you're not working with promises correctly.  You need to have a single point in your code when all of the work in your function is complete (or fails), and use that to send a response.  The promise returned from ref.on("value") needs to be taken into account.  Right now, your function is going to time out because you never send a response.

Comment: i figured it out...i wrapped a promise around the googleclients promise and it works